# Type 'IConnectionState' is not assignable to type '{ connected: false; type: "none"; }'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recoiljs

So, I think my typescrpt linter is short circuiting because, I cant for the life of me figure out why this linting error keeps being raised.

```
Type 'IConnectionState' is not assignable to type '{ connected: false; type: "none"; }'
```

Below is my code, which you can clearly see, should have no consequence.

```
export interface IConnectionState {
    connected: boolean;
    type: 'none' | 'player' | 'host';
}

export const ConnectionState: RecoilState<IConnectionState> = atom({
    key: 'connectionState',
    default: {
        connected: false,
        type: 'none'
    }
});
```

If it helps, I'm using recoil. But looking at the recoil types, `RecoilState` should type takes a subtype of the `default` value given to its options object.

I'm so lost.

Answer (score 1):

I see a similar problem with a simpler interface.

```
export const myState: RecoilState<boolean> = atom({
  key: 'myState',
  default: false,
});

// Type '<RecoilState<false>' is not assignable to type 'RecoilState<boolean>'.
```

I can fix it by either declaring `default: false as boolean`, or, probably better, by adding the generic `<T>` in the method call:

```
export const myState: RecoilState<boolean> = atom<boolean>({
  key: 'myState',
  default: false,
});
```

Or you can leave out the type declarations completely and TypeScript figures it out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the linter is working as expected. You are setting the type of `ConnectionState` to be `IConnectionState` but you never include the property `key` in the interface.

Interface `IConnectionState` is correct but it should be nested within another Interface.

```
const NONE = 'none';
const PLAYER = 'player';
const HOST = 'host';
const CONNECTIONSTATE = "connectionState";

type TType = typeof NONE | typeof PLAYER | typeof HOST;

interface IConnectionStateDefault {
    connected: boolean;
    type: TType
}

interface IConnectionState {
    key: typeof CONNECTIONSTATE,
    default: IConnectionStateDefault
}


export const ConnectionState: RecoilState<IConnectionState> = atom({
    key: "connectionState",
    default: {
        connected: false,
        type: 'none'
    }
});
```

If `IConnectionState` has more `key` values to it then just do the same as I did with `TType` where you form a union over the possible types that `key` can exist as.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've been doing in our monorepo.
Create a global file for the ALL keys to try to keep awareness that you don't want any collisions since the there is one Recoil registry.

```
export enum GlobalRecoilKeyEnum {
     ATOM_SOME_BOOLEAN_KEY= "ATOM_SOME_BOOLEAN_KEY",
}
```

Create a regional file of atoms (Nx allows me to isolate access with linting.)

```
export const SomeBooleanAtom = atom({
    key: GlobalRecoilKeyEnum.ATOM_SOME_BOOLEAN_KEY,
    default: false
});
```

Ways I access in Functional Components.

```
const isSomeBoolean: boolean = useRecoilValue<boolean>(SomeBooleanAtom);
const setSomeBoolean: SetterOrUpdater<boolean> = useSetRecoilState<boolean>(SomeBooleanAtom);
const [isPractice, setSomeBoolean]: [boolean, SetterOrUpdater<boolean>] = useRecoilValue<boolean>(SomeBooleanAtom);
```